# flatMap over list of custom objects in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, flatmap

I'm getting an error when running flatMap() on a list of objects of a class. It works fine for regular python data types like int, list etc. but I'm facing an error when the list contains objects of my class. Here's the entire code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext 

sc = SparkContext("local","WordCountBySparkKeyword")

def func(x):
    if x==2:
        return [2, 3, 4]
    return [1]

rdd = sc.parallelize([2])
rdd = rdd.flatMap(func) # rdd.collect() now has [2, 3, 4]
rdd = rdd.flatMap(func) # rdd.collect() now has [2, 3, 4, 1, 1]

print rdd.collect() # gives expected output

# Class I'm defining
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    # Representation, for printing node
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value


def foo(x):
    if x.value==2:
        return [node(2), node(3), node(4)]
    return [node(1)]

rdd = sc.parallelize([node(2)])
rdd = rdd.flatMap(foo)  #marker 2

print rdd.collect() # rdd.collect should contain nodes with values [2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
```

The code works fine till marker 1(commented in code). The problem arises after marker 2. The specific error message I'm getting is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'node'`

How do I resolve this error?

I'm working on ubuntu, running pyspark 1.4.1

Comment: rename the heading please!

Comment: Please suggest a new heading or add edits to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error you get is completely unrelated to `flatMap`. If you define `node` class in your main script it is accessible on a driver but it is not distributed to the workers. To make it work you should place `node` definition inside separate module and makes sure it is distributed to the workers.

1. Create separate module with `node` definition, lets call it `node.py`
2. Import this `node` class inside your main script:

   ```
   from node import node
   ```
3. Make sure module is distributed to the workers:

   ```
   sc.addPyFile("node.py")
   ```

Now everything should work as expected.

On a side note:

- [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) recommends  CapWords for class names. It is not a hard requirement but it makes life easier
- `__repr__` method should return [a string representation of an object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). At least make sure it is a `string`, but a proper representation is even better:

  ```
  def __repr__(self):
       return "node({0})".format(repr(self.value))
  ```