# parallelize in pyspark, function with several parameters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am a beginner in spark. And I am trying to parallelize millions of executions of a single function:

```
def evaluate_discriminant(ratios, healthy, default, data_provider):
...
```

keeping healthy, default and data_provider constants, I am writting

```
f = lambda p: evaluate_discriminant(p, healthy, default, data_provider)
ratios_sets = [ ['r0'], ['r1'], ['r0', 'r1']]
ratios_RDD = sc.parallelize(ratios_sets)
results = ratios_RDD.map(f)
results.collect()
```

But in collect I get an error TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '**getnewargs**' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Any hints?

Comment: @zero323 evaluate_discriminant is the function defined before. It accepts four parameters, ratios a list, healthy a list. default a list and data_provider an object. I expect calls like f(["r0"], healthy, default, data_provider) and f(["r0", "r1"], healthy, default, data_provider)

Comment: It means that this code is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. It is most likely somewhere in `evaluate_discriminant` and not related to Spark.

Comment: My point is that this is not reproducible. If we use dummy functions like this: `def evaluate_discriminant(ratios, healthy, default, data_provider): return True` everything works just fine.

Comment: Indeed I'd defined lots of functions and they work perfectly. The question is more related to the nature of the objects we cans send as parameters. ratios, healthy and default are lists, "native" python objects. But data_provider is an object whose class I'd defined.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32792271/1560062?. If not please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @zero323 I know that answer. The fact here is more concerned with parameters. I'd rewrote all the evaluate_discriminant function for using data_provider as a dictionary. And it works perfectly. The remaining question is why it cannot be made using a user defined object, in this case data_provider?

Comment: Once again, without a reproducible example there is no way to tell what is going wrong.